# Dynamically deserialize Json to C# object

Tags: c#, json.net

my requirement is to dynamically map the json to C# model using newtonsoft.json or any other.

Let say i have these classes in my C# project.

`ModelA {string FirstName}`
`ModelB{int DepartmentId}`

so if i get json as `{"FirstName":"John"}`, it should resolve to `ModelA` object. likewise for json `{"DepartmentId":8}`, it should resolve to `ModelB`

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<**What should come here as i want this dynamic**>(**Json for ModelA or ModelB**);
```

How to acheive this?

Editing question.
Thanks Guru for solutuon.

the other part of requirement is the model i will resolve from json, i need to pass the type of resolved Model to the generic method as below (i.e. in place of *T where T is class*). How to do this.
`_unitOfWork.Repository <T where T is class>.Add(modelA)`

doing something like `Type type = typeof(modelA)` and then doing `unitOfWork.Repository <type>.Add(modelA)` gives error ***type is variable but is used like type*** Please help. looking this for long time. could not find satisfying solution anywhere.

Comment: You will need a custom `JsonConverter` that checks for the presence of the appropriate property and deserializes to that model.  See [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) for how.

Comment: Does [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) answer your question sufficiently, or do you need more precise help?  If so, where are you confused?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Guru. Will try the solutions in the link you provided and post here the results.

Answer (score 2):

Using [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474/2501279) usually is a preferable option but if you need just to parse those two models in some cases you can take "shortcut" version and parse json to `JObject` and convert it into an object "on the spot":

```cs
public class ModelA
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
public class ModelB
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

var json_str = "{\"FirstName\":\"John\"}";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json_str);
if (jObject.ContainsKey("FirstName"))
{
    var a = jObject.ToObject<ModelA>();
    Console.WriteLine(a.FirstName);
}
else if(jObject.ContainsKey("DepartmentId"))
{
    var b = jObject.ToObject<ModelB>();
    Console.WriteLine(b.DepartmentId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guru for solution. Have edited question for next part of requirement. How will all this work if i have around 100 models

Comment: @Pankaj TBH it should be a separate question. Also I don't understand why do you need such handling - you can call required method with correct generic type parameters inside  `if` statements.